# Is it okay to use DMCA takedown notices to remove my content from SCRAPER sites?

Tags: support, legal, licensing, copyright, attribution

<s>I've</s> (okay, it wasn't entirely me) found yet another SCRAPER site, and have reported it to Stack Exchange through the standard route. This scraper is somewhat exceptional in that it's scraping a majority of SE sites in near-realtime. I've discovered a lot of my own content on the scraped site.

Since the terms of the CC BY-SA 3.0 license aren't being followed, under section 7 of that license, the scraper's license is terminated and the rights granted to them under it are revoked. Hence, to them, the work they're holding is copyrighted and they have no right to use it.

Is it okay from a SE perspective to send them a DMCA takedown notice for my own content? It seems that I'm legally within my rights to, but is this something SE would prefer we didn't do so that when they're contacted by SE there is more stuff there to work with?

Comment: What do you plan to do when they ignore your notices?

Comment: @RobertLongson Nothing, most likely. If they ignore a DMCA notice, going through the full legal process is time consuming and not something I'm inclined to do.

Comment: Seems like a waste of your time then.

Comment: @RobertLongson Not necessarily. There's a chance, though admittedly small, that they'll co-operate with the notice. Especially given that I'd be sending it to the registrar's abuse contact, rather than just the website admin.

Comment: Not to forget that if the scrapper site is hosted in another country, DMCA notice can be hard(or almost impossible..) to enforce.

Comment: Of course it is ok. In fact, as copyright holder, you are the only person who can legally do something concrete. Moreover, if the scraper happens to be in good faith, you're doing useful Creative Commons/copyleft/free culture education. See also the FAQ for more material: http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/200178/15 See some examples where direct intervention has been effective: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/2074/32575

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We have no preference either way. If you would like to take the reins and send some notices yourself, go for it. The content belongs to you and if someone is using it inappropriately, you have the authority to say something about it. I can only caution anyone doing so to make sure that they really are breaking the license, and don't go around just sending takedown notices to every scraper site they run across without looking at it.

The process we follow is quite minimalistic. We do track scrapers, but we rarely ever contact them. The majority of them go offline with a couple of months without us ever having to do a single thing, or rank so badly in Google that no one ever sees them anyways (we have reports from back in December when we first started using this tracker, for sites that *are* still online but have only ever received the single report currently recorded). When we *do* contact them, we send them emails to try and get them to comply with the terms first, rather than sending takedown notices.

If you'd rather just wait it out or let us contact them, that's fine. **If you contact a scraper site yourself**, it would be really helpful if you replied to the same ticket about that site, or just sent us an email mentioning the site and that you did so - just so we can make a note of it in our tracker that *someone* has already contacted them previously.